# android adb usb speed

Tags: android, performance, usb, adb

I'm trying to copy large file from an Android device using the adb interface.
The copying speed is 1470 KB/s.
Where this limitation is coming from?
1470 KB/s is ~ 12 Mbit /s is the USB 1.1 limit.
Is the copying limitation is the USB 1.1?
Can I set it to use USB 2?

This limitation is found both on HTC and on Samsung devices.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

copying with adb pull and adb push is not the same as copying with mounded sdcard to the pc as disc storage. What I am trying to tall you is that when you connect your phone with your pc by default you are in charge only mode, you can change this to disk storage and copying will go faster if you use copy/paste  not adb....

Comment: But when I monitor the phone CPU during the file transfer it stays under 15%. What I don't understand is were is the bottleneck?